# Why do some PostHistory 'partner' events not match up?

Tags: support, data-dump

There are some events that get logged in the PostHistory database that, as far as I can tell, always happen together:

- a post gets merged: `PostMergeSource`, `PostMergeDestination`
- a post is created: `InitialBody`, `InitialTitle`, `InitialTags`
- similar for rollbacks: `RollbackBody`, `RollbackTitle`, `RollbackTags`

So why, when running a query over Worldbuilding's database, do I get these results?

```
Site            History Type Name       Instances
-------------------------------------------------
worldbuilding   Initial Body            25658
worldbuilding   Initial Title           4391
worldbuilding   Initial Tags            4391
worldbuilding   Rollback Body           49
worldbuilding   Rollback Title          23
worldbuilding   Rollback Tags           14
worldbuilding   Post Merge Destination  7
worldbuilding   Post Merge Source       1
```

It would seem to make sense for the numbers for each partner event to be the same, yet they're not. Why is this? Am I misinterpreting the events?

---

<sub>Data from the data dump imported into a MySQL database programmatically. Query:</sub>

```
SELECT
    `ph`.`Site` AS 'Site',
    `pht`.`Name` AS 'Type Name',
    COUNT(`ph`.`PostHistoryTypeId`) AS 'Instances'
FROM `PostHistory` AS `ph`
INNER JOIN `PostHistoryTypes` AS `pht` ON `ph`.`PostHistoryTypeId` = `pht`.`Id`
GROUP BY `ph`.`PostHistoryTypeId`, `ph`.`Site`
ORDER BY COUNT(`ph`.`PostHistoryTypeId`) DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Easy money that `Initial Body` contains not only answers but also tag wikis. And I'd also bet that Rollbacks are split by whether they affect various parts of the post.

Answer (score 2):

Answers do not have titles or tags, so `InitialBody` is expected to be larger, while `InitialTitle` and `InitialTags` are equal.

`Rollback*` revisions are dependent on what fields had modifications, so you can have 1 - 3 (body, title, and tags) corresponding events for the same rollback for questions, and body rollbacks for answers.

<s>I'm not positive about the merge information though, I'm looking into that.</s> Records corresponding to deleted content are typically removed from the data, so while you'll typically always have `PostMergeDestination` records, `PostMergeSource` records might be harder to come by.

In the case of Worldbuilding, the single `PostMergeSource` points to a non-deleted [merge stub](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3116/scientific-accuracy-alien-communication-ideas?noredirect=1) which might be behaving differently because it was [migrated, closed, and then locked](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/3116/revisions) before being merged.

Comment: Huh, of course. Just me being slow and not realising answers are a thing around here.

Comment: My guess for merge events would be that some of those source posts have been deleted and so they no longer appear in the data dump.

Comment: @AdamLear Yeah, that seems reasonable. I wasn't sure why there was one record, but it seems that question had a bit of an involved history that might have prevented the stub from being killed, I guess?

Comment: @TimStone It could also just be something that hasn't *yet* been deleted at the time the data dump was produced. If memory serves, stubs are removed after 30 days, not immediately.

Comment: Merge stubs (not migration stubs) are not automatically deleted unless they qualify for one of the normal rules (closed, abandoned). They're often removed by moderators however, particularly when merging *exact* duplicates from the same author.